# Counting number of words in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to count the number of words from a rich textbox in C# the code that I have below only works if it is a single line. How do I do this without relying on regex or any other special functions.

```
string whole_text = richTextBox1.Text;
string trimmed_text = whole_text.Trim();
string[] split_text = trimmed_text.Split(' ');
int space_count = 0;
string new_text = "";

foreach(string av in split_text)
{
    if (av == "")
    {
        space_count++;
    }
    else 
    { 
        new_text = new_text  + av + ",";
    }
}

new_text = new_text.TrimEnd(',');
split_text = new_text.Split(',');
MessageBox.Show(split_text.Length.ToString ());
```

Comment: Here's a hint for your homework: look at the [Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) property of the RichTextBox to retrieve the RTB's contents.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since you are only interested in **word count**, and you don't care about individual words, `String.Split` could be avoided. `String.Split` is handy, but it unnecessarily generates a (potentially) large number of `String` objects, which in turn creates an unnecessary burden on the garbage collector. For each word in your text, a new `String` object needs to be instantiated, and then soon collected since you are not using it.

For a homework assignment, this may not matter, but if your text box contents change often and you do this calculation inside an event handler, it may be wiser to simply iterate through characters manually. If you really want to use `String.Split`, then go for a simpler version like [Yonix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8784662/69809) recommended.

Otherwise, use an algorithm similar to this:

```
int wordCount = 0, index = 0;

// skip whitespace until first word
while (index < text.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]))
    index++;

while (index < text.Length)
{
    // check if current char is part of a word
    while (index < text.Length && !char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]))
        index++;

    wordCount++;

    // skip whitespace until next word
    while (index < text.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(text[index]))
        index++;
}
```

This code should work better with cases where you have multiple spaces between each word, you can test the [code online](https://ideone.com/L9EXlh).

Comment: Could someone explain why this answer is faster than alternatives? Like: var count = text.Count(x => x == ' '); or like: var count = Math.Ceiling((double) text.Length / 6); Where 6 is average word length in Dutch + 1 for space.

Comment: @Blackunknown: the point is not that it's not faster, it's just correct: 1) you can have more than one whitespace character between words, and even whitespace characters at the beginning/end of the text, 2) whitespace characters can be tabs, line-feeds and carriage-returns too, 3) dividing with the average word length would obviously give you an approximate result in many cases, and a completely wrong result in many other cases.

Comment: @Blackunknown: But it is indeed faster in C# compared to `String.Split`, because `String.Split` allocates heap space for each word and copies the characters there. So if you have a text with 1000 words, `String.Split` will create 1000 string instances, copy the entire text there, even though you actually don't need these strings at all. And then the garbage collector will have to collect them at some point later, which also introduces latency. For a small homework assignment, that might be fine too, as long as the student is aware of these implications.

Answer (score 72):

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] {' ', '\r', '\n' };
whole_text.Split(delimiters,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

Comment: This would be the "there are better ways to do this" part that I mentioned in my answer ;) +1.

Comment: +1 for `RemoveEmptyEntries`. It makes a difference if there are multiple whitespace characters in a row.

Comment: Good speed and less memory usage. The optimization is quite superb.

Comment: Excellent idea.

Comment: Should also add the tab character '\t' to the delimiters.

Comment: This answer fixes the multiple whitespace issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/77798620/9610801

Answer (score 4):

There are some better ways to do this, but in keeping with what you've got, try the following:

```
string whole_text = richTextBox1.Text;
string trimmed_text = whole_text.Trim();

// new line split here
string[] lines = trimmed_text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

// don't need this here now...            
//string[] split_text = trimmed_text.Split(' ');

int space_count = 0;
string new_text = "";
```

Now make two foreach loops. One for each line and one for counting words within the lines.

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // Modify the inner foreach to do the split on ' ' here
    // instead of split_text
    foreach (string av in line.Split(' '))
    {
        if (av == "")
        {
            space_count++;
        }
        else
        {
            new_text = new_text + av + ",";
        }
    }
}

new_text = new_text.TrimEnd(',');

// use lines here instead of split_text
lines = new_text.Split(',');
MessageBox.Show(lines.Length.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This was a phone screening interview question that I just took (by a large company located in CA who sells all kinds of devices that starts with a letter "i"), and I think I franked... after I got offline, I wrote this. I wish I were able to do it during interview..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debug.Assert(CountWords("Hello world") == 2);
    Debug.Assert(CountWords("    Hello world") == 2);
    Debug.Assert(CountWords("Hello world    ") == 2);
    Debug.Assert(CountWords("Hello      world") == 2);
}

public static int CountWords(string test)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool wasInWord = false;
    bool inWord = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
    {
        if (inWord)
        {
            wasInWord = true;
        }

        if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(test[i]))
        {
            if (wasInWord)
            {
                count++;
                wasInWord = false;
            }
            inWord = false;
        }
        else
        {
            inWord = true;
        }
    }

    // Check to see if we got out with seeing a word
    if (wasInWord)
    {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `Lines` property mentioned in @Jay Riggs comment, along with [this overload of String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) to make the code much simpler. Then the simplest approach would be to loop over each line in the `Lines` property, call `String.Split` on it, and add the length of the array it returns to a running count.

EDIT: Also, is there any reason you're using a RichTextBox instead of a TextBox with `Multiline` set to `True`?

Answer (score 1):

I use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for grabbing word count in a string. Do note, however, that double spaces will mess the count up.

```
    public static int CountWords(this string line)
    {
        var wordCount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
            if (line[i] == ' ' || i == line.Length - 1)
                wordCount++;
        return wordCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This fast and simple extension will count all the words including removing all consecutive whitespace characters. Here, we fetch all punctuations available in the text and remove them upon splitting.

Also, there is no need to explicitly specify any delimiters for whitespace characters inside `Split()` as this is handled automatically.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace System
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static int CountWords(this string text)
        {
            char[] punctuationCharacters = text.Where(char.IsPunctuation).Distinct().ToArray();
            var words = text.Split().Select(x => x.Trim(punctuationCharacters));
            return words.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).Count();
        }
    }
}
```

And the basic usage will be:

```
int wordCount = whole_text.CountWords();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Best solution so far. I like that it can be extended as well if you require any custom checking on the items on the list

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is on the right path. I would do something like, passing the text property of richTextBox1 into the method. This however won't be accurate if your rich textbox is formatting HTML, so you'll need to strip out any HTML tags prior to running the word count:

```
public static int CountWords(string s)
    {
    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i - 1]) == true)
        {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[i]) == true ||
            char.IsPunctuation(s[i]))
        {
            c++;
        }
        }
    }
    if (s.Length > 2)
    {
        c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We used an adapted form of Yoshi's answer, where we fixed the bug where it would not count the last word in a string if there was no white-space after it:

```
public static int CountWords(string test)
{
  int count = 0;
  bool inWord = false;

  foreach (char t in test)
  {
    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(t))
    {
      inWord = false;
    }
    else
    {
      if (!inWord) count++;
      inWord = true;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
class Program{
public static void Main(string[] args){
        //Enter the value of n
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] s = new string[n];
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        //enter the elements
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            s[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        string str = "";
        //Filter out duplicate values and store in arr
        foreach(string i in s){
            
            if(str.Contains(i)){
  
                }else{
                    arr.Add(i);
                }
                str += i;
        }
        //Count the string with arr and s variables
        foreach(string i in arr){
            int count = 0;
            foreach(string j in s){
                if(i.Equals(j)){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(i+" - "+count);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
int wordCount = 0;
bool previousLetterWasWhiteSpace = false;

foreach (char letter in keyword)
{
    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(letter))
    {
        previousLetterWasWhiteSpace = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (previousLetterWasWhiteSpace)
        {
            previousLetterWasWhiteSpace = false;
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at counting the words in a string while also being as efficient as possible. Using a Span to ensure no allocations.

```cs
    public static int WordCount(this string s)
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<char> span = s.AsSpan();
        int wordCount = 0;

        while (!span.IsEmpty)
        {
            while (!span.IsEmpty && char.IsWhiteSpace(span[0]))
                span = span.Slice(1);

            if (!span.IsEmpty)
                wordCount++;

            while (!span.IsEmpty && !char.IsWhiteSpace(span[0]))
                span = span.Slice(1);
        }

        return wordCount;
    }
```

Tests:

```cs
            Assert.True("".WordCount() == 0);
            Assert.Equal(1, "hello".WordCount());
            Assert.Equal(2, "hello world".WordCount());
            Assert.Equal(3, "hello world test".WordCount());
            Assert.Equal(4, "hello world test test".WordCount());

            // sentence with punctuation
            Assert.Equal(4, "hello world, test test.".WordCount());

            // multiple sentences
            Assert.Equal(6, "hello world. test test. Hello there.".WordCount());

            // spaces before and after
            Assert.Equal(4, " hello world. test test ".WordCount());
            Assert.Equal(4, "    hello world.   test test       ".WordCount());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int WordCount(string str)
{        
    int num=0;
    bool wasInaWord=true;;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        return num;
    }

    for (int i=0;i< str.Length;i++)
    {
        if (i!=0)
        {
            if (str[i]==' ' && str[i-1]!=' ')
            {
                num++;
                wasInaWord=false;
            }
        } 
            if (str[i]!=' ')
            {
                wasInaWord=true;                
            }
    }
    if (wasInaWord)
    {
        num++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for the code in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str;
        int i, wrd, l;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        Console.Write("\n\nCount the total number of words in a string 
        :\n");
        Console.Write("--------------------------------------------------- 
        ---\n");
        Console.Write("Input the string : ");
        str = Console.ReadLine();

        l = 0;
        wrd = 1;

        foreach (var a in str)
        {
            sb.Append(a);
            if (str[l] == ' ' || str[l] == '\n' || str[l] == '\t')
            {
                wrd++;
            }
            l++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.Replace(' ', '\n'));
        Console.Write("Total number of words in the string is : {0}\n", 
        wrd);
        Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
input.Split(' ').ToList().Count;
```

Answer (score -2):

This can show you the number of words in a line

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
string[] word = line.Split(' ');
Console.WriteLine("Words " + word.Length);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also do it in this way!! Add this method to your extension methods.

```
   public static int WordsCount(this string str)
    {
        return Regex.Matches(str, @"((\w+(\s?)))").Count;
    }
```

And call it like this.

```
  string someString = "Let me show how I do it!";
  int wc = someString.WordsCount();
```

Comment: this gives wrong answer if we have multiple spaces or a "\r\n" linebreak between the words.