# how do i count the words in a string list

Tags: c#, count, overloading

I am constantly running into an overload problem,
I have looked it up but nothing seems to look like my scenario...
I was hoping that the people here could help me.
An example of my code looks as followed.

```
string s = textbox.text;
char[] delimiter = {' '};
string[] word = s.split(delimiter); //this gets a set of words from s.split
for (int i = 0; i <= word.length; i++) //I also tried word.count()
{
    int ii = 0;
    int counter = wordlist.count;
    bool test1 = false;
    while (test1 == false || ii != counter +1)
    {
        if (word[i] == wordlist[ii]) //this is where it gets stuck. It wants to load more word[i] than what there are in the list... 
        {
            //function gets preformed
            test1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ii++;
        }            
    }
}
```

please help me, this part of my script is vital...
thank you for your time!

Comment: what is `wordlist` in this context?

Comment: oh sorry, wordlist is a preloaded set of words, the code basically needs to match the word you typed with the words it knows.
Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting number of words in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784517/counting-number-of-words-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Sorry, it was the only question it would allow, I checked everything else it suggested but nothing matched. Basically, the word[i] keeps overloading when it needs to stop at its last entry. that's what's the problem... the functions I tried is count and length in the for function, and both goes over the amount of words in word[]

Comment: int i = 0; i < word.length; i++ Get rid of the <= equal sign. Typical off by one error.

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes, I have just tried this, and it is still going over the amount in string[] word...

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `string[] words = s.Split(' ');`

Even if we say your `word` is `s.Split(' ');` then it should be `string[] words = word` not `string[]=word`

And to count how much words are in that array just do `int howManyWords = words.Length;`

Also if you want to go through loop as many times as there are words in list you should do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < words.Lenght; i++)
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I tried this and I still got the following error
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
And it is still on the same string[] word[i]

Comment: You have answer in comment by Sam Marion. Change `<=` to `<`. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

While your question is very unclear (you should post what error you are getting at the least it would have made answering much easier) you cleared it up in the comments. What you are getting is an index out of range exception.

You need to change your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= word.length; i++)
```

To

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) // preferable
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= word.length - 1; i++) // not preferable
```

Arrays are index at 0 not 1. The length property will give you the total number of elements in the array. When you get to your last index the value of i will be greater than the number of elements because you started counting at 0.

You also need to change your while loop because you have an out of range exception happening there. Its the same problem except this time you added one to make it even worse.

```
while (test1 == false && ii != counter - 1)
```

Change it to a minus so it never goes out of range. Also change the logic to an && instead of || with the or when it finds a match it will never increment the ii so it will be stuck forever in the while.

You would also want to break out of the loop once you find the match.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I tried the middle one and I still got the following error
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
And it is still on the same string[] word[i]

Comment: Why is this ii != counter +1 shouldn't it be ii != counter - 1

Comment: thank you for your reply, I don't remember exactly why I wrote it as is, but it works to stop the while loop.

Comment: You will possibly get an out of range exception with it like that also you need to change the || in the while loop to an && or if it does find a match you will never leave the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found my problem. it was because there were no words in wordlist[] for it to read... my bad!

I should just place in a prevention method next time...

But thank you guys for your assistance! the code is now working as should!