# Count words inside a ASP .NET Core Blog

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to program a estimated time to read counter for my blog. I've seen [here](https://youdid.blog/howto-geschaetzte-lesezeit-angeben/) how to do this in PHP.
Now I would like to do this in ASP.NET Core. Currently i'm stumbling about counting words. How can i do this in C#?

Comment: In c# at server-side? In JS while writing the article? We need more information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting number of words in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784517/counting-number-of-words-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. In general i needed a solution for javascript. But just now i have solved it. I added this to the top of my cshtml:

```
@model BlogStory
@{
    var word_count = @Model.Body;
    var counts = word_count.Split(' ');
    var resultcount = counts.Length;
    var minutes = resultcount / 250;
    var seconds = resultcount % 250 / (250 / 60);
    var str_minutes = (minutes == 1) ? "Minute" : "Minuten";
    var str_seconds = (seconds == 1) ? "second" : "Sekunden";
    var returnstring = "";
    if (minutes == 0) {
        returnstring = seconds + str_seconds + ' ' + " (" + resultcount + ')' + " Words";
    } else {
        returnstring = minutes + str_minutes + ' ' + seconds + str_seconds + " (" + resultcount + ')' + " Words";
    }  
}
```

Comment: I am assuming that you are doing this for some static content (or at least not being changed by the user that needs to know the time to read), in that case, it would likely be optimal to do this on server side (controller or possibly view model) rather than client side and will help keep your logic and view separate.

Comment: Ok. Thanks i'll check it.

Comment: Since you aren't using `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` why not just use `word_count.Count(ch => ch == ' ')+1`?

Comment: @NetMage Thank you for that hint. It works perfectly :-)